# PHP how to call a define dynamically

Tags: php, string, dynamic, concatenation

I want to do a concatenation to call my define but php don't want.

By example :

```
define('FOO_1', 'string 1');
define('FOO_2', 'string 2');
```

I want to call it dynamically :

```
$id = 1;
echo FOO_.$id;
```

But it displays :

> FOO_1
>   (not "string 1");

How can I call my define dynamically ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By using `constant()`

```
echo constant('FOO_'.$id);
```

See doc here: http://php.net/constant

*credits to Yent*